# If hashed password is in DB can villain use that hashed password in input box in login

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, hash

I read that [this is the module (bcrypt)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs) to use to do login, password saving stuff. To my understanding, the main problem it solves is that if a hacker gets access to your database and you don't hash the password a hacker can easily copy and paste the username and password and get access to the account. the module provides methods to compare the hashed string and the password sent through `req.body.password`.

My understanding of hashing is that it takes a text and create a long string of random characters. In apps that string is stored in the mongoDB `password` field how does that prevent hackers from copying and pasting the random string into the input box and login like that? so I'm not seeing the point of hashing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Primer

Ok, let's first see what really happens (under optimal circumstances, though slightly simplified):

1. A user creates a new password.
2. Your application hashes the password and persists the hashed password for further reading
3. If the user logs in, the application takes the password provided by the user, runs it through bcrypt, which hashes this password and then this hashed password is compared to the stored password. If they match, that password provided via login is the same as provided during password creation – which is the only thing you need to know.

So, having that clear, we have to look at the different attack scenarios.

## The attacker gained read access to the database

Ok, the attacker got read access to the database. Bad enough. Personal data leaked. Actually, he can copy all data. But let's set that aside and have a look at the passwords. The attacker might see something like this

```
Username    Password
admin       $2a$04$acaUVljoRAvazzj6YX7K2eEfUt9PHVVgr.ahZ4xLzb9292u4Bv9Sm
jdoe        $2a$04$cTUGYHixAGwdTU90XflsI.G2FQuj/p4nVYW2Tp3HsCeUGs5MPmR.e
```

Now, hash functions are considered cryptographically secure if, and only if, brute force is the easiest way to calculate the input data from the hash value. With the hash sizes and computing power of today, you'd need a *very* long time to calculate the passwords from their hashes.

Following the procedure described above, while our attacker has read access to the database, he can not simply take the hash value and paste it as the password – the application would take the hash, hash it again and the subsequent check for matching will fail. Benefits?

1. During normal operations, even the admin will be unable to read the password the user chose. People tend to use a password on multiple instances. We all know we should not, but it happens. Would you like the SO admins to know the password you chose? ;) How much less an attacker?
2. Since the attacker will be unable to log in by acquiring the hash values, he can not *do* something on behalf of a legitimate user, for example buy something.
3. The attacker will have to put *considerable* resources if he wanted to brute force the hash values in order to obtain clear text passwords. To give you an impression: Assuming that we can do 65536 hashes/s, we have 2<sup>232</sup> possibilities, so we would need ~ 2.18*10<sup>62</sup> *years* to brute force the hash, which is about 1.59*10<sup>52</sup> times the age of the universe. Even with a *lot* of cores doing parallel processing (say the whole planetary system converted to computers), it will take very, very, very long.
4. The attacker will be unable to identify identical passwords, since with bcrypt, even the same input data will not produce the same hash value – it is a pretty advanced hash algorithm. [The two hashed above were created from the same input](https://gist.github.com/mwmahlberg/9609ec2ec9189be7842c). This works because every hash contains its own (pseudo-randomly generated, iirc) [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)). That would force an attacker to do a brute force attack on each found salt value to identify identical values or clear text values.

So, with hashing, we have made it impossible for an attacker who got read access to obtain any information about the passwords from just seeing the hash values (other that they seem to be bcrypt hash values).

## The attacker gained write access to the database

Ok, you are pwned. The attacker gained write access. He can wreak havoc on your application, copy all data and *delete* it afterwards. Hope you have your backup current and working.

Now he can simply set a new bcrypt hash for "admin" and "jdoe" and he can do anything those users can do. Doh!

But let's look what he can not do: As with read access, he can not calculate the clear text password from a given hash. So there is no risk that the attacker gains access to the user's Maskbook, Gibber or Instanonsense accounts, even when the user used the same password as within your application.

## Conclusion

With storing bcrypt password hashes, we have several advantages:

1. The password is hidden from the admins
2. Even when an attacker obtains the hash value, he can not calculate the clear text password easily
3. An attacker can not make any deductions on identical passwords, since each input value will produce a different hash value, even with the same input. So he'd have to do a brute force for each salt value. See above.
4. When the attacker only gains read access, he can not gain access to the application.

Hope that makes the advantages of storing hashed passwords clear.

Answer (score 3):

As you said the function will create a hash of the string from passed to it. Hash is not random but shuffled input, using the same algorithm and input result will be the same and it can't be decoded. If attempting to hash the hashed password will produce something completely different.

```
md5('password') = '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99'
md5('5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99') = '696d29e0940a4957748fe3fc9efd22a3'
```

Comment: ok it's not random, it's shuffled input. But can you use the hash stored in the DB in the input box on the form to login. if someone puts in the input box the hash and and I have `if(req.body.password == user.password)` would that would work? and does `compatreSync` make it so that when the user enters the original password it converts it to a hash so you could compare them.  or something like that?

Comment: To handle login attempt find user by username then hash password sent in the request and compare against one stored in user document.

Answer (score 0):

When a user wants to log in, he needs to send the *original password*. Your application will then calculate the hash of the password again and compares it to the stored hash. If the user would send the hash, the application would calculate the hash again, and it would not match with the value in the database.

Maybe your confusion comes from using JavaScript, what indicates that you calculate the hash client-side. Hashing should be done *server-side* though, one sends the original password and not the hash over the internet.

Answer (score -3):

Well if your passwords, usernames and hash string are stored in a database then yes a hacker can use that hash to decrypt everything. However if someone is sniffing your login/connection then they won't get your username and password in plain text nor will they get the hash key.

Comment: To help clarify thing. Question: When I hash a password with `bcrypt.hash(req.body.password)` that gives me a random long string. If a hacker knows that string  he can input that into the password field on a form and get access? I'm doing `bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, /the long string/)` in `app.post(/login)`

Comment: "can use that hash to decrypt everything" — No, they can't. Hashes are one way.

Comment: "However if someone is sniffing your login/connection then they won't get your username and password in plain text" — Yes they will. That's why we use SSL.